# Are there any risks of migrating from Hudson to Jenkins for CI?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson

Please let me know if there are risks at all for migrating from Hudson to Jenkins.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's unlikely that this question will receive a definitive answer (other than Yes) because it is too broad and there are many possible risks in different environments. If you're looking for advice, I recommend posting to the Jenkins users mailing list (see http://jenkins-ci.org/content/mailing-lists) with a description of your environment and the plugins you use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as [Dave Bacher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/172599/dave-bacher) said. If you don't understand what you are doing, don't do it.